# Non-admin users cannot have access to any LISTVIEW in vtiger crm 7.1.0

Tags: crm, vtiger, vtigercrm

Standard User are not able to View/List Contacts, Organizations, Opportunity, etc

This was a problem I have been struggling for couple of days, which were `SOLVED` completely by making sure `ALL VTIGER` database and tables have same collation. Since probably other `VTIGER` users possibly can face similar problem, I am summarizing the solution.
1) When Installing `VTIGER` from scratch, make sure to `CREATE DATABASE/USER`, instead of letting `VTIGER INSTALLATON` do it, prior to run `VTIGER` installation script and make sure to set its `COLLATION` to recommended "`utf8_general_ci`" (I used this method)
2) Case `VTIGER` was migrated, or after import and configurations, recoimmended solutions might be (I did not test, but very likely that it will work) altering collations and converting database and actual tables to target collation e.g. "`utf8_general_ci`". Please make sure to get `FULL BACKUP` of `VTIUGER` database before start making any changes to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to Database. Get a backup of database.
runthe following query in database-

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vtiger_cv2group (
cvid int(25) NOT NULL,
groupid int(25) NOT NULL,
KEY vtiger_cv2group_ibfk_1 (cvid),
KEY vtiger_groups_ibfk_1 (groupid)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vtiger_cv2role (
cvid int(25) NOT NULL,
roleid varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vtiger_cv2rs (
cvid int(25) NOT NULL,
rsid varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vtiger_cv2users (
cvid int(25) NOT NULL,
userid int(25) NOT NULL,
KEY vtiger_cv2users_ibfk_1 (cvid),
KEY vtiger_users_ibfk_1 (userid)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Now check.